# Can I sign a new certificate with a previously paid for certificate

Tags: tls, x.509

For the last few months, I have been using self signed certificates to provide ssl for a system that I have been building. We are now getting ready to start getting external users on the system, but this will require purchasing a certificate.

This system will be one of several others that will be running on a sub-domain, but may move to its own domain later on. There will also be several other secured systems running in a similar fashion.

We would also like to put our main site on ssl only too.

So, although I know I can use a wildcard certificate, could I purchase an ssl certificate for the main site, then create a signing request for the sub-domain, and sign it with the purchased certificate, and would that validate for visitors to the sub-domain?

Comment: see http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47267/can-i-buy-a-signing-valid-certificate-for-internal-use and http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18188/what-kind-of-certificate-do-i-need-to-be-able-to-sign-my-own-subdomain-certifica/27969#27969

Comment: I disagree that 18188 is a duplicate as it only talks about wildcards, but yes to 47267

Comment: You might want to read more than the first paragraph of 18188 before arguing that it is only about wildcards. Not only is the question similar to yours, also the answer is appropriate to your question. Just look at the all the other paragraphs of the response.

Comment: Apologies, speed reading took over. Started on wildcards, then moved to the `Another Strategy` section, and concluded non-relevance when the page didn't contain the word usage (but did extension)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the certificates you purchase for SSL are not valid for certificate signing.  This is enacted via [usage extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Extensions_informing_a_specific_usage_of_a_certificate).

It is possible to buy signing certificates which can be used for that purpose, but it is prohibitively expensive - the certificate authorities do not, after all, wish to put themselves out of business.

Comment: damn, thought it might be something along those lines. It would seem counter-intuitive from a business perspective to create such allowances :(

Comment: The genie's wish cannot be used to get more wishes.